# Displaying app release date in iPhone App.

Tags: iphone, date, release

I want to show the app release date in info view of iphone app. My app is in under development and we want others to know when the app was released.

The app released date is displayed on iTunes App Store.

Thanks in Advance
Aamir Mansuri

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about other methods, but you can first submit the app onto the app store and have the release date set by you. In your code you can set the release date to this date and submit the app. Even after the app is approved it won't be released till the release date and you can go into itunes and control it.